# Solr, have to enter whole word

Tags: xml, solr

I have items in my index with several words in each filed (text_general). Eg. "one to three four".

I have made a jQuery autosuggest querying my index, but i need to type one of the words from my text_field to get a respond. Eg. "one". "O" or "On" won't give me a result.

This has worked before with the same settings, so I can't figure out why it doesn't anymore. Only thing I really changed is the data I indexed and that I now have 2 entities in my data-config.xml, instead of one.

I have copied several fields to the filed:

```
<field name="test" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true">
```

(See further below)

I have have played around with multiValue, but it didn't seem to be the problem. Any suggestions what to look at?

It's Solr 4.4.

data-config.xml

```
<entity name="product" dataSource="sqlServer" pk="ProductID" query="SELECT 
    ProductID,
    ProductNumber,
    ProductName,
    ProductShortDescription,
    ProductLongDescription,
    ProductPrice,
    ProductFeatures,
    ProductSymbols,
    ProductApplications
    FROM EcomProducts">

    <field column="ProductID" name="Id"/> 
    <field column="ProductNumber" name="ProductNumber"/> 
    <field column="ProductName" name="Name"/>           
    <field column="ProductShortDescription" name="ProductShortDescription"/> 
    <field column="ProductLongDescription" name="ProductLongDescription"/>  
    <field column="ProductPrice" name="ProductPrice"/> 
    <field column="ProductFeatures" name="ProductFeatures"/> 
    <field column="ProductSymbols" name="ProductSymbols"/> 
    <field column="ProductApplications" name="ProductApplications"/> 
</entity>   

<entity name="tip" dataSource="sqlServer" pk="Id" query="SELECT 
    Id,
    TipsContentHeader,
    TipsContentText,
    TipsPageId
    FROM ItemType_TipsFifContent">

    <field column="Id" name="Id"/>
    <field column="TipsContentHeader" name="Name"/>
    <field column="TipsContentText" name="TipsContentText"/>
    <field column="TipsPageId" name="TipsPageId"/>
</entity>
```

schema.xml

```
 <field name="Id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
 <field name="Name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />  

 <field name="TipsContentText" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" /> 
 <field name="TipsPageId" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />  

 <field name="ProductNumber" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" /> 
 <field name="ProductShortDescription" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
 <field name="ProductLongDescription" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" /> 
 <field name="ProductPrice" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
 <field name="ProductFeatures" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
 <field name="ProductSymbols" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
 <field name="ProductApplications" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />


  <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="Name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="TipsContentText" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="ProductShortDescription" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="ProductLongDescription" dest="text"/>

<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

Comment: What's the query being sent to solr?

Comment: Can you paste the fieldType definition of "text_general"?

Comment: My guess is that `text_general` has a `WhiteSpaceFilter` that indexes by word, but you are looking for `NGram` filters?

Comment: @dwhelan I'm using SolrNet to query. 
Looks like this: https://gist.github.com/PaulSorensen/6792009

Comment: @Aeham You can see the fieldType for "text_general" here - it's just standard from the default configuration. https://gist.github.com/PaulSorensen/6792025

Comment: @Srikanth Venugopalan I have been looking into NGram, but the weird thing is it has worked before, with the same configuration (without NGram tokenizer). Should I just replace the solr.StandardTokenizerFactory in my filedType definition with NGram tokeziner?

Comment: @egeek that does not show the query that you are running, can you write down what query you pass to that function? if that is only a string I really donøt see how that could have worked before

Comment: I would not recommend the NGram tokenzier. This will increase your index size dramaticaly. Can you tell us how your solr query currently looks like ? Maybe the problem is that you don't do a wildcard search in your query like o* or on*.

Comment: @zbindigonzales You were completely right! I changed the query in my code, and stripped the wildcard in the beginning and end of the query. After inserting *q* it now works again, thanks! Can you throw an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend the NGram tokenzier. This will increase your index size dramaticaly. Can you tell us how your solr query currently looks like ? 
The problem is that you don't do a wildcard search in your query like o* or on*

Comment: You were completely right! I changed the query in my code and stripped the wildcard in the beginning and end of the query. After inserting it again (* q *) it now works again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use N-Grams so you find matches on letters and not whole words. You can find an example [here](http://searchhub.org/2009/09/08/auto-suggest-from-popular-queries-using-edgengrams/)